# Parse Json file with Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, json

I'm trying to parse a json file into my html but without success. Here is my Json file:

```
{
   "menu":[
      {
         "id":"contact",
         "leaf":true,
         "description":"testing",
         "link":"",
         "content":"contactUs.html",
         "cssClass":"static-content",
         "menu":null
      },
      {
         "id":"rules",
         "leaf":false,
         "description":"Sports",
         "link":"",
         "content":"",
         "cssClass":"",
         "menu":[
            {
               "id":"types",
               "leaf":true,
               "description":"Wager",
               "link":"",
               "content":"wagerTypes.html",
               "cssClass":"static-content wager-types",
               "menu":null
            },
            {
               "id":"odds",
               "leaf":true,
               "description":"Odds",
               "link":"",
               "content":"oddsAndLines.html",
               "cssClass":"static-content",
               "menu":null
            },
            {
               "id":"policies",
               "leaf":true,
               "description":"Policies",
               "link":"",
               "content":"rulesAndPolicies.html",
               "cssClass":"static-content rules-policies",
               "menu":null
            },
            {
               "id":"bonuses",
               "leaf":true,
               "description":"onuses",
               "link":"",
               "content":"sportsBonuses.html",
               "cssClass":"static-content",
               "menu":null
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "id":"conditions",
         "leaf":false,
         "description":"Conditions",
         "link":"",
         "content":"",
         "cssClass":"",
         "menu":[
            {
               "id":"termsOfService",
               "leaf":true,
               "description":"Service",
               "link":"",
               "content":"termsOfService.html",
               "cssClass":"static-content",
               "menu":null
            },
            {
               "id":"privacy",
               "leaf":true,
               "description":"Privacy Policy",
               "link":"",
               "content":"policy.html",
               "cssClass":"static-content",
               "menu":null
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "id":"view",
         "leaf":true,
         "description":"View in: Mobile | Full Site",
         "link":"",
         "content":"delete.html",
         "cssClass":"static-content",
         "menu":null
      }
   ]
}
```

And at the moment I've this:

```
var menu = [];

    $.getJSON( "menu.json", function( data ) {
          var items = [];
          $.each( data.menu, function( key, url, val  ) {
            items.push( "<li id='" + key.id + "'> <a href=' "+ url.content +" '>  "  + val.description + "</a></li>" );
          });

          $( "<ul/>", {
            "class": "dropDownList",
            html: items.join( "" )
          }).appendTo( "#wrapper" );
    });
```

If I use just 2 parameteres, I can get the description from the Json file but If I add another parameter seems that I got an error...
How can I access all that content and also, how can i get the values from the menu.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need to have a recursive rendering

```
function process(data, $ct) {
    if (!data || !data.length) {
        return;
    }
    var $lis = $.map(data, function (menu, i) {
        var $a = $('<a />', {
            href: menu.content,
            text: menu.description
        });
        var $li = $('<li >', {
            id: menu.id
        }).append($a)
        if (menu.menu && menu.menu.length) {
            process(menu.menu, $li)
        }
        return $li.get();
    });

    $("<ul/>", {
        "class": "dropDownList",
        html: $lis
    }).appendTo($ct);
}

process(data.menu, '#wrapper')
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/0j2sv1z1/)